# Are arguments loaded into the cache for empty functions?

Tags: c++, caching, compiler-optimization, static-functions

I know that C++ compilers optimize empty (static) functions.

Based on that knowledge I wrote a piece of code that should get optimized away whenever I some identifier is defined (using the `-D` option of the compiler).
Consider the following dummy example:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef NO_INC

struct T {
    static inline void inc(int& v, int i) {}
};

#else

struct T {
    static inline void inc(int& v, int i) {
        v += i;
    }
};

#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = 42;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        T::inc(a, i);

    std::cout << a;
}
```

The desired behavior would be the following:
Whenever the `NO_INC` identifier is defined (using `-DNO_INC` when compiling), all calls to `T::inc(...)` should be optimized away (due to the empty function body). Otherwise, the call to `T::inc(...)` should trigger an increment by some given value `i`.

I got two questions regarding this:

1. Is my assumption correct that calls to `T::inc(...)` do not affect the performance negatively when I specify the `-DNO_INC` option because the call to the empty function is optimized?
2. I wonder if the variables (`a` and `i`) are still loaded into the cache when `T::inc(a, i)`  is called (assuming they are not there yet) although the function body is empty.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: There are no blanket answers about optimizations. It depends on your compiler, its QoI and your build options. The only way to know is to examine the generated assembly and/or profile.

Comment: I don't understand the second question in 1). What does the `#else` branch have to do with anything if `-DNO_INC` is specified.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Seems reasonable. I removed the second part of 1.

Comment: The question title itself demonstrates a misconception: Function arguments are loaded into registers, not the cache. They only go through the cache if they come from memory, but both `a` and `i` will be kept in registers in this example (in an optimized build) and never touch the cache. Further, compiler optimizations nowadays tend to go way beyond "will it skip a parameter load for an empty function" - as the answers show, the whole program might be optimized out due to a combination of several optimizations. Whether each one happens isn't always easy to predict, so always check your binary.

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks for the comment. Of course they are loaded into registers in this simple example. However, there may still be cases for which `a` and/or `i` may have to be loaded from memory, right?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of possibilities why that might be necessary (or not optimized away from the compiler perspective). The point was just that "the variables are loaded from memory" is mostly orthogonal to "this function is called". Of course, if the compiler can determine that calling the function is pointless it may eliminate the variables (or loads) altogether, but those are usually separate concerns. Again though, checking the binary in your concrete case is both the simplest and most reliable way to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is an very useful tool to look at the assembly of your generated program, because there is no other way to figure out if the compiler optimized something or not for sure. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/43M_SH).

With actually incrementing, your `main` looks like:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .LBB0_1
        lea     eax, [rdi - 1]
        lea     ecx, [rdi - 2]
        imul    rcx, rax
        shr     rcx
        lea     esi, [rcx + rdi]
        add     esi, 41
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
        mov     esi, 42
.LBB0_3:
        mov     edi, offset std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

As you can see, the compiler completely inlined the call to `T::inc` and does the incrementing directly.

For an empty `T::inc` you get:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, offset std::cout
        mov     esi, 42
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

The compiler optimized away the entire loop!

> Is my assumption correct that calls to `t.inc(...)` do not affect the performance negatively when I specify the `-DNO_INC` option because the call to the empty function is optimized?

Yes.

> If my assumption holds, does it also hold for more complex function bodies (in the `#else` branch)?

No, for some definition of "complex". Compilers use heuristics to determine whether it's worth it to inline a function or not, and bases its decision on that and on nothing else.

> I wonder if the variables (`a` and `i`) are still loaded into the cache when `t.inc(a, i)` is called (assuming they are not there yet) although the function body is empty.

No, as demonstrated above, the loop doesn't even exist.

Comment: This behaviour can only be expected because the inline keyword is used. Although functions may or may not be inlined with or without the keyword, it guarantees that they **can** be and, in this case, should be.

Comment: @Pelipap No, that's not true. `inline` doesn't guarantee that the function is inlined.

Comment: It is true the way I put it. I wrote it guarantees that the function "**can**" be inlined.

Comment: An empty function is **supposed to be** inlined iff the inline keyword is used. If it isn't, the compiler has an optimization issue. If the inline keyword isn't used, the compiler might not even be able to inline the function, depending on how it is used and compiled.

Comment: @Pelipap `inline` only means that the function is allowed to have definitions in more than one translation unit. It has been unrelated to the compiler's inlining of code for the last couple of decades or so.

Comment: Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/FVMWEa), I removed the inline keyword and the compiler does the exact same think. Inline is mainly used by the linker as @molbdnilo stated correctly!

Comment: @Pi The compilation results **have to differ** although the linkage results might not. The question is not about a specific assembly but about good practice. It would be bad practice not to inline these functions.

Comment: @molbdnilo It means, amongst other things, that it cannot be compiled to a function by itself. Without `inline` the function will be in the compiled object albeit it may be removed when linking to an excecutable. Therefore, defining it without inline indicates and allows the function to be used from within other units which means that it **cannot be** inlined so using `inline` is necessary to guarantee that the compiler can (and, in this case, should) inline the function.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my assumption correct that calls to t.inc(...) do not affect the performance negatively when I specify the -DNO_INC option because the call to the empty function is optimized? If my assumption holds, does it also hold for more complex function bodies (in the #else branch)?

You are right. I have modified your example (i.e. removed cout which clutters the assembly) in [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/X86IDK) to make it more obvious what happens.

The compiler optimizes everything away and outouts

```
main:                                   # @main
        movl    $42, %eax
        retq
```

Only 42 is leaded in eax and returned.

For the more complex case, however, more instructions are needed to compute the return value. [See here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qPC8Ym)

```
main:                                   # @main
        testl   %edi, %edi
        jle     .LBB0_1
        leal    -1(%rdi), %eax
        leal    -2(%rdi), %ecx
        imulq   %rax, %rcx
        shrq    %rcx
        leal    (%rcx,%rdi), %eax
        addl    $41, %eax
        retq
.LBB0_1:
        movl    $42, %eax    
        retq
```

> I wonder if the variables (a and i) are still loaded into the cache when t.inc(a, i) is called (assuming they are not there yet) although the function body is empty.

They are only loaded, when the compiler cannot reason that they are unused. See the second example of compiler explorer.

**By the way**: You do not need to make an instance of T (i.e. `T t;`) in order to call a static function within a class. This is defeating the purpose. Call it like `T::inc(...)` rahter than `t.inc(...)`.

Comment: Of course I should rather use `T::inc(...)`. I overlooked that. Thanks for the pointer, I adapted code and question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `inline` keword is used, you can safely assume 1. Using these functions shouldn't negatively affect performance.

Running your code through

g++ -c -Os -g

objdump -S

confirms this; An extract:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    T t;
    int a = 42;
    1020:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    1025:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
    1027:   39 fa                   cmp    %edi,%edx
    1029:   7d 06                   jge    1031 <main+0x11>
        v += i;
    102b:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    102d:   ff c2                   inc    %edx
    102f:   eb f6                   jmp    1027 <main+0x7>
        t.inc(a, i);
    return a;
}
    1031:   c3                      retq
```

(I replaced the cout with return for better readability)